# Can't connect docker nginx server to local mysql database

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker

I am trying to connect docker nginx server to local MySQL database.But I am getting this error instead:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = homestead and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

Here is my docker composer code:

```
version: "3"
networks:
 laravel:
services:
site:
  build:
   context: .
   dockerfile: nginx.dockerfile
  container_name: nginx
  ports:
   - 8080:80
  volumes:
   - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
  depends_on:
   - php
   - redis
 networks:
   - laravel

php:
 build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: php.dockerfile
container_name: php
volumes:
  - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
networks:
  - laravel

redis:
 image: redis:alpine
 container_name: redis
 restart: unless-stopped
 ports:
  - 6379:6379
 networks:
  - laravel

composer:
 build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: composer.dockerfile
 container_name: composer
 volumes:
  - ./src:/var/www/html
 working_dir: /var/www/html
 depends_on:
   - php
 user: laravel
 entrypoint: ["composer", "--ignore-platform-reqs"]
 networks:
  - laravel

artisan:
 build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: php.dockerfile
 container_name: artisan
 volumes:
  - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
 working_dir: /var/www/html
 user: laravel
 entrypoint: ["php", "/var/www/html/artisan"]
 networks:
  - laravel
```

Comment: How exactly are you trying to connect one to the other?  Can you show the relevant nginx configuration?

Comment: @DavidMaze I have edited the question. please have a look at it

Comment: You should also provide your php connection string (hint: the issue is probably the difference between 'localhost' and '127.0.0.1')

Comment: how do I add connection string to php.@symcbean I am new to docker

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this simply by adding this

> host.docker.internal

to my database host. Here is the code example

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=host.docker.internal
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not shure that it will help you in that way you needs
You need to know you gateway ip, to connect to your local machine.

```
docker network inspect laravel | grep Gateway
```

Then put this ip to DB host.

PS Be aware after restart it will be changed.